# Mean of one vector of list of lists

Tags: r, loops, lapply, sapply

I have following data set

```
myList <- split(x = ChickWeight, f = ChickWeight$Diet)
```

and i want to calculate the average of weights by list, i.e four different averages. one possible solution is

```
a<-lapply(myList, `[[`, 1)
lapply(a, mean)
```

But is it possible if i can have mean function in "a". i.e

```
a<-lapply(myList, `[[`, 1, mean)
```

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. What do you expect `a` to look like? The same as `lapply(a, mean)`? Or to have it both the mean and the raw data on separate elements?

Comment: I mean if i can use mean as argument in the lappply function for code below
a<-lapply(myList, `[[`, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function `colMean` to use in `lapply`.

```
colMean <- function(x, col) colMeans(x[, col, drop=FALSE])

lapply(myList, colMean, col='weight')  ## also: `col=1`
# $`1`
# weight 
# 102.6455 
# 
# $`2`
# weight 
# 122.6167 
# 
# $`3`
# weight 
# 142.95 
# 
# $`4`
# weight 
# 135.2627
```

Also works for multiple columns.

```
lapply(myList, colMean, col=c('weight', 'Time')
# $`1`
# weight      Time 
# 102.64545  10.48182 
# 
# $`2`
# weight      Time 
# 122.61667  10.91667 
# 
# $`3`
# weight      Time 
# 142.95000  10.91667 
# 
# $`4`
# weight      Time 
# 135.26271  10.75424
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function -

```
lapply(myList, function(x) mean(x$weight))
#Also by position of the column
#lapply(myList, function(x) mean(x[[1]]))

#$`1`
#[1] 102.6455

#$`2`
#[1] 122.6167

#$`3`
#[1] 142.95

#$`4`
#[1] 135.2627
```

If the dataset is not already splitted you can use `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(weight~Diet, ChickWeight, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(myList, ~ .x %>%
     pull(weight) %>%
     mean)
```

-output

```
$`1`
[1] 102.6455

$`2`
[1] 122.6167

$`3`
[1] 142.95

$`4`
[1] 135.2627
```

---

Or using `base R` from the original data

```
tapply(ChickWeight$weight, ChickWeight$Diet, FUN = mean)
       1        2        3        4 
102.6455 122.6167 142.9500 135.2627
```